# overflow-x on tables outer container isn't working

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive-design, overflow

I'm having issues creating responsive tables that scroll when the content area is no longer wide enough to accommodate the table.

I'm wrapping each table in a div, and applying overflow-x to it. Neither 'scroll' or 'auto' is working, and I haven't been able to figure out what style is preventing it from working as expected.

It works fine at the smallest size (once the page shifts to a single column). But as soon as the sidebar is sitting next to the content area, the table loses its scroll, and the sidebar pushes off the side of the browser.

https://www.biometricupdate.com/201712/determining-the-best-biometric-reader-for-an-application

Here's a snippet containing the code in question. It's out of context of the rest of the site, and I have my doubts that the answer can be found without taking a whole lot of surrounding code into consideration, but this is a scaled-down version of the precise code that's giving me problems:

```css
main {
  color: #333;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

main>.primary {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

main>.secondary {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 372px;
}

.tablescroll {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<main class="max-outer">
  <div class="primary">
    <div class="tablescroll">
      <table id="tablepress-1" class="tablepress tablepress-id-1">
        <thead>
          <tr class="row-1 odd">
            <th class="column-1">Technology</th>
            <th class="column-2">Convenience</th>
            <th class="column-3">Acceptability</th>
            <th class="column-4">Speed</th>
            <th class="column-5">Environment</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="row-hover">
          <tr class="row-2 even">
            <td class="column-1">Fingerprint Recognition</td>
            <td class="column-2">Most widely used biometric; intuitive and easy to use; finger placed on sensor; lit with red light</td>
            <td class="column-3">There is still some resistance to enrolling a fingerprint biometric; FAR is extremely low; FRR affects a small number of users; high quality readers reduce false rejects</td>
            <td class="column-4">Throughput is high, reads biometric in less than 1 second</td>
            <td class="column-5">Indoor, outdoor and ruggedized models</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
  </div>
</main>
```

So far, I've tried a variety of overflow settings, and I've tried setting the table itself to width:auto.

If you view the code using browser Developer Tools, you'll see that the table.tablepress is wrapped in a div.tablescroll, with overflow applied.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I've been rooting through the browser developer console trying to figure out what's preventing the scrolling from applying to the table, and I'm at a loss. I'm hoping someone's encountered a similar issue and recalls what object or coding technique on surrounding elements needed to be addressed. I've never seen this technique fail like this before.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. External sites may be malicious, flagged by filter systems, or even removed at a later stage (making the question useless). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I can try, but the issue could be related to the elements surrounding the problematic object, and requires viewing at different screen sizes to see the issue. I'll update my post with minimal snippets and we'll see if it helps...